# Fabric.js touch events

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, touch, fabricjs

I created a program and tested it and everything is fine, but then i tested it on an iPad but the only touch events that is working are the click and drag.

I tested the demo provided by this link http://fabricjs.com/touch-events and its working on the device.

I also noticed that when I dont include the fabric.min.js library the touch events work but other functionalities dont (get allot of errors).

I did download the custom fabric file and i did select gestures so it should be supported, and the fabric.js and fabric.min.js are version 1.6.3.

Is there any implementations i need to do?
Thank you for your time and efforts for this amazing library, looking forward to hearing from you.